# PowerConnect 3548p SNTP and web interface not working

Tags: networking, switch, subnet, dell-powerconnect

I have been unable to get SNTP and access to the web interface working properly on a Dell PowerConnect 3548p.

In the logs, this message appears over and over again:

> 04-Jan-2000 20:19:29 :%MNGINF-W-ACL: Management ACL drop packet
>   received on interface Vlan 172 from 172.17.0.3 to 172.18.0.10 protocol
>   17 service Snmp

172 is the management vlan.

172.17.0.3 is the DNS server
172.18.0.10 is the switch's IP address.

The DNS server and the switch are located on different subnets and separated by routers.

I am unable to access the web interface of the switch from the 172.17.x.x subnet.

I can only access the web interface of the switch if I am accessing it from the 172.18.x.x subnet.

There is also a managed linksys switch on the 172.18.x.x subnet on the 172 vlan, which has no problem with SNTP. I can also access it from the 172.17.x.x network. So, it stands to reason that this is not a firewall or routing issue, but with the 3548p switch.

I suspect the issue is with management permissions/ACLs on the 3548p switch, but that's about as much as I've been able to determine so far.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the switch have a Default Gateway configured? If not, it needs to in order to communicate across subnets.

Comment: It looks like that might be it...can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Let us know and if that's it I'll post my comment as an answer.

Comment: ok, the clock on the switch just updated. Yep, that was it. Thanks! :)

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switch needs to have a Default Gateway configured in order to communicate across subnets.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, I had to add SNTP to my management access profile which now is:

```
management access-list "secure access"
permit service ssh priority 1
permit service https priority 2
permit service sntp priority 3
exit
```

The default is deny so an explicit deny at the end of the acl is not required.

Furthermore did pool.ntp.org not work, I ended up adding the ip addresses manually.